# Angular route is not working in my web application

Tags: angularjs

Angular Router is not working in my application. I have a login form, Angular controller, and Welcome page. When I pass the login details and click on submit button, Angular is not routing to welcome.html page.
Below is the code snippet.

**Login Form(AngularForm.html)**

```
 <html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="LoginCtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myAngular">
    <div ng-controller="LoginController">
        <form action="/" id="myForm">
            UserName:
            <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username">
            <br> Password:
            <input type="password" id="passowrd" ng-model="password">
            <br>
            <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Login Controller(LoginCtrl.js)**

```
        var App = angular.module('myAngular', ['ngRoute']);
    App.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'AngularForm.html'
        })
        .when('/welcome',{
              templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
              })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });

    function UserLogin($scope,$location)
    {
        $scope.submit = function(){
           var uname=$scope.username
           var pwd=$scope.passowrd
            if($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin')
               { $location.path('/welcome'); }

        }

    }

App.controller('LoginController',UserLogin);
```

**Welcome Page(welcome.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <h1>Login Successful!!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see `ng-view` in your main html file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to separate the login content from the main `AngularForm.html` file

AngularForm.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="LoginCtrl.js"></script>  
        </head>
        <body ng-app="myAngular">  
            <div ng-view></div>     
        </body>
</html>
```

make sure to add the `<div ng-view></div>` so that partial routes lay on top of this.

make the login HTML like this

login.html

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController">
<form action="/" id="myForm">
    UserName:<input type="text" id="username" ng-model="username"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" id="passowrd" ng-model="password"><br>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Login</button>
</form>  
</div>
```

add a new state called `login` in the config

JS

```
var App = angular.module('myAngular', ['ngRoute']);
App.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'AngularForm.html'
    })
    .when('/login',{
        templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    .when('/welcome',{
          templateUrl: 'welcome.html'
          })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
});

function UserLogin($scope,$location)
{
    $scope.submit = function(){
       var uname=$scope.username
       var pwd=$scope.passowrd
        if($scope.username == 'admin' && $scope.password == 'admin')
           { $location.path('/welcome'); }

    }

}

App.controller('LoginController',UserLogin)
```